# How to get Versionhistory popup on clicking menuitemtemplate

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, version-history

I have following lines of code for menuitemtemplate:

```
 MenuTemplate menuTemplate = new MenuTemplate(); 
menuItem = new MenuItemTemplate("Version History","/_layouts/images/versions.gif");
            menuItem.ClientOnClickScript = "" // what I put there
    menuTemplate.Controls.Add(menuItem);
```

ClientOnClickScript, what should I put there ? so that I can see versionHistory of the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page showing versions is accessible as

```
<siteCollectionURL>/_layouts/versions.aspx?list=<ListID>&ID=<ItemId>&FileName=<ServerRelativeFileUrl>
```

So you need to know ListID, ItemID and ServerRelativeFileUrl as parameters.
)
To launch it via the Javascript you would need something along these lines

```
LaunchVersionsDialog(this, '%ListId%', '%ItemId%', '%ServerRelativeFileUrl%')";

function LaunchVersionsDialog(elm, siteUrl, listId, itemId, serverRelativeFileUrl)
{

var versionsPageUrl = siteCollectionURL + '/_layouts/versions.aspx?list=' + listID + '&ID=' + itemId + '&FileName=' + serverRelativeFileUrl;

var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
options.width = 600;
options.height = 400;
options.url = versionsPageUrl;

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

One more thing missing is passing those parameters to by Setting Attributes from the Server Side Code when you call the function - for that i suggest you read some more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.menuitemtemplate.clientonclickscript.aspx

Comment: What is ServerRelativeFileUrl ? How I get this ?

Comment: Usually it represents a Column on the SPListItem, or it could also very well obtained by using SpListItem.File. In case of document library it does represent the actual file location, whereas for simple list items, it will return something with 1.00, 2.00 etc. at the end